# iOS Swift converting calendar component int month to medium style string month

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

I want to display calendar in this format

[image: visible calendar style date]

to the user. One option is to use "string range" to get the individual calendar components. The second one is to get it using NSCalendar which to me looks like the better one (is it?). So my code is as below. But there are two problems.

1. I am not getting the local time form "hour & minute components"
2. I am getting month in Int. I want it to be in String (month in mediumStyle)

Anyone know how to get what I need? Image attached is what exactly I want to achieve. There I am using three UILabel one for "date", second for "month, year" and third for "time".

Any help would be appreciated.

```
var inputDateString = "Jun/12/2015 02:05 Am +05:00"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let newDate = dateformatterDateString(inputDateString)
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: newDate!)

    let hour = components.hour
    let minutes = components.minute
    let month = components.month
    let year = components.year
    let day = components.day

    println(newDate)
    println(components)
    println(day)     // 12
    println(month)   // 6 -----> Want to have "Jun" here
    println(year)    // 2015
    println(hour)    // 2 ------> Want to have the hour in the inputString i.e. 02
    println(minutes) // 35 ------> Want to have the minute in the inputString i.e.  05
}

func dateformatterDateString(dateString: String) -> NSDate? {
    let dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a Z"
    //      dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    return dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
}
```

Answer (score 27):

You can use DateFormatter as follow:

```
extension Formatter {
    static let monthMedium: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "LLL"
        return formatter
    }()
    static let hour12: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "h"
        return formatter
    }()
    static let minute0x: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "mm"
        return formatter
    }()
    static let amPM: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "a"
        return formatter
    }()
}
extension Date {
    var monthMedium: String  { return Formatter.monthMedium.string(from: self) }
    var hour12:  String      { return Formatter.hour12.string(from: self) }
    var minute0x: String     { return Formatter.minute0x.string(from: self) }
    var amPM: String         { return Formatter.amPM.string(from: self) }
}
```

---

```
let date = Date()

let dateMonth  = date.monthMedium  // "May"
let dateHour   = date.hour12       // "1"
let dateMinute = date.minute0x     // "18"
let dateAmPm = date.amPM           // "PM"
```

Comment: I tried a lot, but I am not able to get the thing I need. The timezone is creating problem. But for now I am using working with the date & time string to display the selected date in my code. So I have posted a new question related to the issues i am facing there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804366/ios-swift-unable-to-update-uilabel-on-first-uidatepicker-selection. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

`NSDateFormatter` has  `monthSymbols`, `shortMonthSymbols` and `veryShortSymbols` properties.

So try this:

```
let dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

let months = dateFormatter.shortMonthSymbols
let monthSymbol = months[month-1] as! String // month - from your date components

println(monthSymbol)
```

Comment: If the time is 11:59Pm, the date at the output is not the same as inputDateString. Can you please review the question above?

Comment: The problem is at your input string conversion to NSDate

Comment: it you want to get the same result for +5:00 just add the same timezone offset to the extension dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 3600*5)

Comment: Currently using Swift 2, and have this shortened to `let months = NSDateFormatter().shortMonthSymbols
            print("\(months[month-1])")`

Answer (score 4):

**Update Swift 5.x Solution:**

Today is `Monday, 20 April, 2020`

```
    let date = Date() // get a current date instance
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter() // get a date formatter instance
    let calendar = dateFormatter.calendar // get a calendar instance
```

Now you can get every index value of year, month, week, day everything what you want as follows:

```
    let year = calendar?.component(.year, from: date) // Result: 2020
    let month = calendar?.component(.month, from: date) // Result: 4
    let week = calendar?.component(.weekOfMonth, from: date) // Result: 4
    let day = calendar?.component(.day, from: date) // Result: 20
    let weekday = calendar?.component(.weekday, from: date) // Result: 2
    let weekdayOrdinal = calendar?.component(.weekdayOrdinal, from: date) // Result: 3
    let weekOfYear = calendar?.component(.weekOfYear, from: date) // Result: 17
```

You can get an array of all month names like:

```
    let monthsWithFullName = dateFormatter.monthSymbols // Result: ["January”, "February”, "March”, "April”, "May”, "June”, "July”, "August”, "September”, "October”, "November”, "December”]
    let monthsWithShortName = dateFormatter.shortMonthSymbols // Result: ["Jan”, "Feb”, "Mar”, "Apr”, "May”, "Jun”, "Jul”, "Aug”, "Sep”, "Oct”, "Nov”, "Dec”]
```

You can format current date as you wish like:

```
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let todayWithTime = dateFormatter.string(from: date) // Result: "2020-04-20 06:17:29"
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let onlyTodayDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date) // Result: "2020-04-20"
```

I think this is the most simpler and updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
I am adding three types. Have a look.

        //Todays Date
        let todayDate = NSDate()
        let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
        let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: todayDate)
        var (year, month, date) = (components.year, components.month, components.day)
        println("YEAR: \(year)  MONTH: \(month) DATE: \(date)")

        //Making a X mas Yr
        let morningOfChristmasComponents = NSDateComponents()
        morningOfChristmasComponents.year = 2014
        morningOfChristmasComponents.month = 12
        morningOfChristmasComponents.day = 25
        morningOfChristmasComponents.hour = 7
        morningOfChristmasComponents.minute = 0
        morningOfChristmasComponents.second = 0

        let morningOfChristmas = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(morningOfChristmasComponents)!
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle
        formatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle
        let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(morningOfChristmas)
        print("dateString : \(dateString)")


        //Current month - complete name
        let dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        let months = dateFormatter.monthSymbols
        let monthSymbol = months[month-1] as! String
        println("monthSymbol  : \(monthSymbol)")


Print Results:

YEAR: 2015  MONTH: 10 DATE: 9
dateString : December 25, 2014 at 7:00:00 AM
monthSymbol  : October
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.x Solution:

```
//if currentMonth = 1
DateFormatter().monthSymbols[currentMonth - 1]
```

Answer:

> January

Answer (score 0):

```
let now = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "LLLL"
let nameOfMonth = dateFormatter.string(from: now)
```